# Command line options/tools to convert OWL/XML to RDF/XML

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

I had written a script which exports a relational database to an OWL/XML file, although I now need the data in RDF/XML format instead. Does anyone know of a command line tool or simple way to do this (convert the OWL synax to RDF)? I'd like to avoid rewriting the script.

I know the University of Manchester has an online syntax converter, but this isn't useful as I need something which can be used offline (and perhaps as part of an automated process). Protege can open OWL files and save them as RDFs, but I can't seem to find info about command line options to do this within it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  Your best bet, if something like this doesn't already exist, is to roll your own using something like the OWL API that already reads and writes both formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a command line tool but if you're willing to write a little Java you can use OWL API (the same api Protege uses) to write your own convertor to any supported syntax.

The code looks like this:

```
OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLOntology o = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(inputFile);
OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("your output file name");
m.saveOntology(o, new RDFXMLDocumentFormat(), out);
out.close();
```

Tutorials and documentation available [here](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/)

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!